# Godot 4 is giving me the error of Too many arguments for "connect()" call. Expected at most 3 but received 4, ... ect in

Tags: godot, godot4

```
`extends Node2D

const SlotClass = preload("res://Inventory/Slot.gd")
@onready var inventory_slots = $GridContainer
var holding_item = null

func _ready():
     for inv_slot in inventory_slots.get_children():
        inv_slot.connect("gui_input" , self , "slot_gui_input", [inv_slot])
        
func slot_gui_input(event: InputEvent, slot: SlotClass):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT & event.pressed:
            if holding_item != null:
                if !slot.item: # Place holding item to slot
                    slot.putIntoSlot(holding_item)
                    holding_item = null
            else: # Swap holding item with item in slot
                var temp_item = slot.item
                slot.PickFromSlot()`
                temp_item.global_position = event.global_position
                slot .putIntoSlot(holding_item)
                holding_item = temp_item
        elif slot.item:
            holding_item = slot.item
            slot.pickFromSlot()
            holding_item.global_position = get_global_mouse_position()
func _input(event):
    if holding_item:
        holding_item.global_position = get_global_mouse_position()`
```

I was following a tutorial for an inventory, the tutorial used Godot 3. whilst I use Godot 4.
This is the code that is giving the error ( < inv_slot.connect("gui_input" , self , "slot_gui_input", [inv_slot]) >, is giving the error)
Error

- Line 9: Too many arguments for "connect()" call. Expected at most 3 but received 4.
- Line 9: Invalid argument for "connect()" function: argument 2 should be "Callable" but is "res://Inventory/Item/Item.gd".
- Line 9:Cannot pass a value of type "String" as "int".
- Line 9: Invalid argument for "connect()" function: argument 3 should be "int" but is "String".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this line:

```
inv_slot.connect("gui_input" , self , "slot_gui_input", [inv_slot])
```

Looks correct for Godot 3, but as you found out, it is not correct in Godot 4.

---

First of all, you no longer specify a method using a `String`. Instead you do this:

```
inv_slot.connect("gui_input", self.slot_gui_input, [inv_slot])
```

In fact, you don't need `self`, you can do this:

```
inv_slot.connect("gui_input", slot_gui_input, [inv_slot])
```

Please notice that here the method name is not followed by parenthesis (`slot_gui_input(...)`), so you are not calling the method, you are making a reference to it... And that reference is a `Callable`.

And second, you do not pass extra parameters to `connect` anymore. Instead you bind them to the `Callable`, like this:

```
inv_slot.connect("gui_input", slot_gui_input.bind(inv_slot))
```

And that line should work.

---

But wait, that is not all. You can also avoid referencing the signal using a `String`, like this:

```
inv_slot.gui_input.connect(slot_gui_input.bind(inv_slot))
```